# Change default mail client

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, evolution, default

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to change my default mail client (To Evolution), I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux but I've gone to `System Settings` >`Details` > `Default Applications` & Change it. Yet when I click the system tray icon thing at the top, it still brings up Thunderbird when I click "Compose New Mail" and what not, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Hi along with changing in Default application list, you need to some more work.You need to install this package to arrange the room in Notification area.

Open your terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type this

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-indicator
```

Then Re-login/Restart to apply the changes.

PS:If you don't want to use Thunderbird , then you'd better uninstall it.

Comment: Uninstalling the default applications that come pre-installed is not at all recommended - even if you don't use them. You are better off leaving it as it is.

Comment: @Aditya My dear Brother ,Actually I don't use any mail client so I have removed it from Applications and I don't see any problem.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Any command I have to run to remove the Thunderbird indicators or will they go as I uninstall it?

Comment: @Totte just uninstall Thunderbird.That will do the trick.

Comment: Still says Thunderbird with the submenus in the dropdown menu, all that did was remove the icon in front of it :P So now I got mail thingies with submenus up there :P

Comment: So now I got two*

Comment: @Totte Sorry for the late reply. I was away. do this in terminal `sudo apt-get purge thunderbird*`